change the position of the example number langsci avm
I would like to be able to change the position of the example number of a langsci AVM. For instance, on the following picture, the number is at the left of the AVM. 
I would like to put it on the right. Could you please help me?
Here is my minimal code.
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{langsci-avm}

\avmdefinestyle{plain}{attributes=\scshape,
values=\scshape,
types=\normalfont, extraskip=0.8em}


\begin{document}

\ex. \label{ex:fstr etre-malin}
\avm[style=plain]{[pred & `\textsc{être-malin} <suj>'\\
suj & [pred & `\textsc{vieille-femme}'\\
def & +\\
genre & 1\\
nbre & sg\\]\\
pol & aff \\
mode & ind\\
tps & perf\\
]
}

\end{document}


The linguex package has no way of putting the number on the right, because this is really not a style that is ever used in linguistics publications, and so it was not designed with this flexibility. For an individual number it's easy enough to put AVM and the number into side-by-side minipage environments. This is obviously not a general solution.
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{langsci-avm}

\avmdefinestyle{plain}{attributes=\scshape,
values=\scshape,
types=\normalfont, extraskip=0.8em}


\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{.55\linewidth}% adjust as needed to move number left or right.
\avm[style=plain]{[pred & `\textsc{être-malin} <suj>'\\
suj & [pred & `\textsc{vieille-femme}'\\
def & +\\
genre & 1\\
nbre & sg\\]\\
pol & aff \\
mode & ind\\
tps & perf\\
]
}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.2\linewidth}
\ex. \label{ex:fstr etre-malin}

\end{minipage}
\end{document}


